# Генератор чисел

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <div class="number">
        <div class="token-number" id="tokenup">
            <span id="tokennumber">160</span> /
            <span id="endTick">9999</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

В JS-файле написан скрипт, который выводит рандомные числа по возрастанию, например:

```
160/9999, 162/9999, 163/9999
```

и так далее.

Но появилась проблема, что когда я захожу на сайт у меня этот "отсчёт" рандомных чисел начинается не с `160` а вообще с нуля, то есть загружается страница, я вижу `/9999`, потом `1/9999` и так далее.

Вот JS скрипт:

```
    let staticNumber = document.querySelector('#tokennumber').textContent
    
    document.querySelector('#tokennumber').textContent =
        localStorage.getItem('tokennumber')
    
    let timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
        let tokennumbercontent = document.querySelector('#tokennumber')
        let tokennumber = localStorage.getItem('tokennumber')
        let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
        let number = +tokennumber + randomNumber
        let endTickNumber = +document.querySelector('#endTick').textContent
        let endTick = (endTickNumber / 100) * 80
        let howMaxNumber = Math.round((+tokennumber * 100) / endTickNumber)
        if (+tokennumber <= endTick) {
            localStorage.setItem('tokennumber', number)
            tokennumbercontent.textContent = number
    
            timerId = setTimeout(tick, 1300)
        } else {
            console.log('end')
        }
    }, 1500)
    timeId()
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема?

Если есть источники с похожими скриптами, то буду рад почитать изучить!!

Прошу прощения, забыл пояснить. Суть кода в том, что он рандомно выводит числа, неважно, чётные/нечётные. То есть, вот в спане прописано со 160 начинать и он должен выводить в html, на страничке 160/9999, потом 161/9999, 163/9999 и так далее. Когда доходит до 9999/9999, то должно сброситься до 5000 допустим, то есть 9999/9999 потом 5034/9999. У меня ещё проблема была в том, что оно до 9999/9999 не доходило, оно либо останавливалось на восьми тысячах с чем, либо на девяти тысячи.

Comment: 1. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119) 2. [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Все правильно, если в момент первого входа `localStorage.getItem('tokennumber')` не существует. А ваша переменная **staticNumber**, которая поидее должна быть началом, нигде не используется. Вот отсчет и идет с пустоты

Comment: @Utheron, рассказал бы что хотел сделать в итоге, поскольку код у тебя довольно сумбурный и понять "замысел" довольно проблематично.

Comment: @ksa, всё, пояснил